# Ansible and docker-py

Tags: docker, ansible

I wrote a task in

```
roles/common/tasks
```

to login to docker hub :

```
 - name: login to docker
  shell: "docker login -e {{ registry_mail }} -p {{ registry_pass }} -u {{ registry_user }} {{ registry_host }}"
```

Then tried pulling the image without calling the credentials via docker-py module:

```
 - name:  start our container
   docker:
        image: repo/container:{{ TAG }}
        name: container
        #registry: "{{ registry_host }}"
        #username: "{{ registry_user }}"
        #email: "{{ registry_mail }}"
        #password: "{{ registry_pass }}"
        publish_all_ports: yes
        state: reloaded
        restart_policy: always
```

docker-py will fail to pull the image unless I provide the credentials.
Is there any way I can login to docker hub with docker-py module without calling the "image" function  or log in to docker and pull the image with docker-py later in other tasks ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to use a shell task to login when you can login directly in the task? Do you have a good use case for this?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Where else do you need to login?

Comment: In all of my roles. And every role has its own docker image but with same repository . I'm trying to write a task with log in 'only' to docker repository in "common" role  then use it in the other roles with just "pulling" the image.

Answer (score 0):

I fainlay solved it, however i found a bug along the way and opened a ticket

```
https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2269
```

Its a problem with docker-py when pulling an image from docker hub